# How to print or send braces ( ) using VBA sendkeys

Tags: vba, excel

i have following code which is not sending braces.

```
sendkeys "a=$(script.sh)",true
```

but it is sending as a=$script.sh

braces are missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SendKeys "a=${(}script.sh{)}", True
```

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim RetVal

    RetVal = Shell("NOTEPAD.EXE ", 1)

    AppActivate RetVal
    SendKeys "a=${(}script.sh{)}", True
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a=$(script.sh)
```