# How can I use square brackets in Application.OnKey? (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I would like to use the key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to call a subroutine in my VBA project. Here is the code I have tried:

```
Appication.OnKey "+%[", "mySubroutine"
```

I have had no problems using other characters with shift and alt, such as lowercase letters and numbers. However, when I try to use the left square bracket, I get the following error:

```
Method 'OnKey' of object '_Application' failed
```

I have also tried to use the left square bracket with all of the different combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>. They all produce the same error.

```
Application.OnKey "^[", "mySubroutine"
Application.OnKey "+[", "mySubroutine"
Application.OnKey "%[", "mySubroutine"
Application.OnKey "^+[", "mySubroutine"
Application.OnKey "^%[", "mySubroutine"
Application.OnKey "^+%[", "mySubroutine"
```

I also tried using the ASCII code for the left square bracket (91) like this:

```
Application.OnKey "+%{91}", "mySubroutine"
```

with no luck.

I also tried using Excel's built-in Chr() function with that ASCII keycode:

```
Application.OnKey "+%" & Chr(91), "mySubroutine"
```

which did not work, either.

I am running Excel 2013. Another computer in our office is running Excel 2003, and though that computer is using Excel4Macro language, it IS able to use the left square bracket to set up a keyboard shortcut.

It seems like Microsoft removed this capability in the newer version of Excel. However, if anyone can figure out a way to make it work, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Application.OnKey "+%{[}", "mySubroutine"
```

Same codes as for SendKeys...

[How to print or send braces ( ) using VBA sendkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011104/how-to-print-or-send-braces-using-vba-sendkeys)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx

> The plus sign "+", caret "^", percent sign "%", tilde "~", and
>   parentheses "()" all have special meanings and must be enclosed within
>   braces "{}". Square brackets "[]" must also be enclosed within braces
>   although they have no special meaning. To specify brace characters
>   themselves, use "{{}" and "{}}".

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! (Why didn't I think of that...)